# Is it possible to show different control in radiobutton list

Tags: c#, asp.net, radiobuttonlist

Is it possible to show different control in radiobutttonlist control.

I need to display radiobuttonlist layout as below image

I am binding radiobuttonlist control through database

[image]

Comment: No, not unless you create a custom ListItem. Maybe you can achieve this without aspnet controls but with pure html/css and just capture the form post collection.

Comment: @VDWWD I am binding radiobutton list through database